# C# Namespace reserved words

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces, windows

I make the following query, is that I am taking a project which contains a class project with namespace Application.ProyectoA is that now I need to use from a windows project and gives me problems with the proper namespace System.Windows.Application, now try thereby instantiate

_viewModel.Item = global :: Application.ProyectoA.ProyectoManager.Get (200);

I've also tried changing the name of the alias and using external alias, but you can not.

but does not recognize "Application.ProyectoA" anyone has any solution for this, change the namespace cumbersome Original is half as this project is used in several places.

Greetings and thank you very much.

Comment: `change the namespace cumbersome Original is half as this project is used in several places.` wat

Comment: I love Google Translator

Comment: "along with hello" i thought it was a Hello World program

Comment: stackoverflow translator, jojojo sorry, but there is an answer related the topic of the question???

Comment: What is the reserved word that's causing trouble?